# Python requests head, just get redirected url and don't follow redirections

Tags: python, python-requests

Im stuck on this. I want to get just the url of a redirected link, I don't need to follow the redirections and visit each link, just get the latest url.

I have this code

```
try:
    r=requests.head(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"},timeout=20, allow_redirects=True)

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
    print(error)

print(r.url)
```

And with some urls I get this message:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.parafarmaciaweb.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /isdin-capsulas-solares-sun-defense-duplo-2x30-capsulas.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMImL2c8Yzm6gIVSLTtCh0DIwyGEAkYCiABEgLNI_D_BwE (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc758ce9550>, 'Connection to www.parafarmaciaweb.com timed out. (connect timeout=20)'))
```

I just need the url and it is in the error: https://www.parafarmaciaweb.com/isdin-capsulas-solares-sun-defense-duplo-2x30-capsulas.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMImL2c8Yzm6gIVSLTtCh0DIwyGEAkYCiABEgLNI_D_BwE

I could **scrape** the url from the error, but there must be a way just to get the URL and skip this error, isn't it?

Any ideas how to get this url without scraping it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every time you get the error does what follows the `?gclid` stay the same or change?
`gclid=EAIaIQobChMImL2c8Yzm6gIVSLTtCh0DIwyGEAkYCiABEgLNI_D_BwE` It looks like the error is returning a key that lets you access the website.

Comment: You are getting the error because Parafarmaciaweb.com is DOWN https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/parafarmaciaweb.com.html

Comment: Thanks @Jortega for your reply. glcid might be a marketing variable to identify the source of the link. Anyways, the gclid is always the same in my tests since I'm always using the same test sources.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh Nair for your reply. I knew the web was down, the thing is that I can't undersand why the redirected url is in the error text but I just can't get it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Set allow_redirects to false and get the redirected url from headers['Location']

```
import requests
r = requests.head(link, allow_redirects=False)
print(r.status_code, r.headers['Location'])
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh Nair, thanks for your reply. This answer do not work in my case becase there are several redirections and your code seem to resolve only the first one. But, you've given to me the answer to the problem. I must write a mixed code in such a way that, i allow_redirects by default and just in case of exception use allow_redirects=False. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Rakesh Nair didn't fully work in my case because there were several redirections in each URL and that code just gave me the first one, so I've solved this by using a two levels strategy. First, I allow_redirects (True) and try to solve the redirection, just in case an exception occurs I use the Rakesh version. The code below works like a charm for me.

Thanks Rakesh!

```
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def resolveLink(link):

    final_link=''
    resolve_error=0
    reply=''
    try:
        r=requests.head(link,timeout=20, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}, allow_redirects=True)
        reply=r.url
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
        try:
            r=requests.head(link,timeout=20, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}, allow_redirects=False)
            reply=r.headers['Location']
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
            resolve_error=1

    if not resolve_error:
        final_link=re.sub("\?.*$","",reply)

    return final_link
```

The line:

```
final_link=re.sub("\?.*$","",reply)
```

Removes exchange tokens from the URL, such as:

```
gclid=EAIaIQobChMImL2c8Yzm6gIVSLTtCh0DIwyGEAkYCiABEgLNI_D_BwE
```